# Remove nth character from middle of string using Shell

Tags: bash, sed

I've been searching google for ever, and I cannot find an example of how to do this. I also do not grasp the concept of how to construct a regular expression for SED, so I was hoping someone could explain this to me.

I'm running a bash script against a file full of lines of text that look like this: 2222,H,73.82,04,07,2012

and I need to make them all look like this:  2222,H,73.82,04072012

I need to remove the last two commas, which are the 16th and 19th characters in the line.
Can someone tell me how to do that? I was going to use colrm, which is blessedly simple, but i can't seem to get that installed in CYGWIN. Please and thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I'd use [**`awk`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) for this:

```
awk -F',' -v OFS=',' '{ print $1, $2, $3, $4$5$6 }' inputfile
```

This takes a CSV file and prints the first, second and third fields, each followed by the output field separator (`","`) and then the fourth, fifth and sixth fields concatenated.

Personally I find this easier to read and maintain than regular expression-based solutions in **`sed`** and it will cope well if any of your columns get wider (or narrower!).

Comment: You don't need to redefine OFS for every line of the file: `awk -F, -v OFS=, '{print ...}'`

Answer (score 2):

This will work on any string and will remove only the last 2 commas:

```
sed -e 's/\(.*\),\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\)$/\1\2\3/' infile.txt
```

Note that in my sed variant I have to escape parenthesis, YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

It should work :

```
sed -e 's~,~~4g' file.txt
```

remove 4th and next commas

Comment: It might be easier to see as `s/,//4g`

Answer (score 1):

> I also do not grasp the concept of how to construct a regular
>   expression for SED, so I was hoping someone could explain this to me.

The basic notation that people are telling you here is: `s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/`

Your PATTERN is a regular expression, which may contain parts that are in brackets.  Those parts can then be referred to in the REPLACEMENT part of the command.  For example:

```
> echo "aabbcc" | sed 's/\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)/\2\3\1/'
bbccaa
```

Note that in the version of sed I'm using defaults to the "basic" RE dialect, where the brackets in expressions need to be escaped.  You can do the same thing in the "extended" dialect:

```
> echo "aabbcc" | sed -E 's/(..)(..)(..)/\2\3\1/'
bbccaa
```

(In GNU sed (which you'd find in Linux), you can get the same results with the `-r` options instead of `-E`.  I'm using OS X.)

I should say that for your task, I would definitely follow Johnsyweb's advice and use awk instead of sed.  Much easier to understand.  :)

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "2222,H,73.82,04,07,2012" | sed -r 's/(.{15}).(..)./\1\2/'
```

Take 15 chars, drop one, take 2, drop one.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e 's/(..),(..),(....)$/\1\2\3/' myfile.txt
```