# Cut characters from position from string in bash

Tags: linux, string, bash, cut

I have the following string, which it will always be 35 characters long:

```
S202SCTRXBAVCWPJAC001181204120000.N
```

I would like to cut 3 characters (position 17-19), **JAC** in this case, to remain only

```
S202SCTRXBAVCWP001181204120000.N
```

Is there a way to achieve this in bash?

Comment: [BashFAQ #100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100) ("How do I do string manipulations in bash?") is pertinent. So is [the bash-hackers' page on parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe).

Comment: BTW, closely related (but optimized for processing large files rather than single variables) is [I need to delete string from position X to position Y on each line in a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25293481/i-need-to-delete-string-from-position-x-to-position-y-on-each-line-in-a-text-fil)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove the middle n characters from lines in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18186481/608639), [How to remove characters in the middle of a string in bash](https://superuser.com/q/836265/173513), [Remove nth character from middle of string using Shell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10217016/608639), [How to delete a substring using shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13570327/608639), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with the answer by Charles Duffy. If you know you want specifically "JAC" instead of what indices you want removed, you could do:

```
str="S202SCTRXBAVCWPJAC001181204120000.N"
echo "${str/JAC/}"
```

Comment: Thank you, all seems to be working but not in a case statement. I am trying like this `case $FORM in
 JAC )
  BNAME=$(basename $FILE) ;;
#  FNAME=${BNAME:0:15}${BNAME:18} ;;
  FNAME=${BNAME/$FORM/} ;;
  MSGIF="pacs.xxx.sct.s.scf" ;;
  cp -p $FILE $DDIRD/$FNAME ;;

esac
` and get error `./ScriptRBRS.sh: line 22: syntax error near unexpected token `;;'
./ScriptRBRS.sh: line 22: `             FNAME=${BNAME/$FORM/} ;;'`

Comment: Interesting the OP accepted this answer, as this only works to cut the three characters at position 17-19 if those three characters are `JAC`, so it works for what the OP said "**JAC** in this case" but it doesn't work for the general case of characters 17-19 for any string. Charles Duffy's answer works for any case.

Answer (score 4):

```
strIn=S202SCTRXBAVCWPJAC001181204120000.N
strOut=${strIn:0:15}${strIn:18}
echo "$strOut"
```

...uses only bash-built-in functionality to emit:

```
S202SCTRXBAVCWP001181204120000.N
```

...as it emits the first 15 characters starting at position 0, then everything after position 18.

Comment: Thank you, all seems to be working but not in a case statement. I am trying like this `case $FORM in
 JAC )
  BNAME=$(basename $FILE) ;;
#  FNAME=${BNAME:0:15}${BNAME:18} ;;
  FNAME=${BNAME/$FORM/} ;;
  MSGIF="pacs.xxx.sct.s.scf" ;;
  cp -p $FILE $DDIRD/$FNAME ;;

esac
` and get error `./ScriptRBRS.sh: line 21: syntax error near unexpected token `;;'
./ScriptRBRS.sh: line 21: `             FNAME=${BNAME:0:15}${BNAME:18} ;;'`

Comment: You need to use `;`, not `;;`, to separate multiple commands within the same `case` entry -- `;;` is only for separating completely different cases. So that's a general using-`case`-correctly issue, not something specific to this answer.